# Create an unknown number of objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, for-loop

I need to create a specific number instances of an object based on a variable. so the pseudo code looks kinda like this

```
for(int x; x < aInt; x++) {
    //create object and initialize it
}
```

how would I do that and create a different object each time with a different name and memory location?

Answer (score 2):

Stick the reference in a `NSMutableArray` (or a `NSArray`, given that you appear to know the size in advance).

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]

for(int x; x < aInt; x++) {
    //create object and initialize it
    YourObject *o = [[YourObject alloc]init];
    [array addObject:o];
    [o release];
}

// do whatever you need to do with the objects
```

A `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` is certainly an option as well, depending on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(YourIntegerValue)];
for(int x; x < aInt; x++) {
    //create object and initialize it
    [objectsArray addObject:(YourObject)];
}
```

Don't forget to **release** the array after you're done working with it!